# Auto adjust text size to fit the layout Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

Is there's way to change the text size to fit **screen-width** ? 
i have Header with long title, the problem is on small size screen that title goes to another line. i would like to change font size to fit the whole text in 1 line

Comment: Take a look on autosizing TextView documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: I think There's no native support but, You can check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: but thats one for API level 26

Comment: So what's the problem? The question has already been answered.

Answer (score 18):

Android officialy supports autosizing.for implementing dynamic size you should set autoSizeTextType attribute to uniform and set autoSizeMaxTextSize and autoSizeMinTextSize attributes to your desired size.

*attention : for apis below 26 you should use 'app' prefix for attributes instead of 'android' .

and finally you should have a textView like this for stretching text to screen-width:

```
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Hello, how are you today"
                    android:textSize="100sp"
                    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
                    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
                    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    />
```

Comment: as mentioned https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYrpEAz_A1U 
avoid using layout height to wrap content, instead use match_parent or specified height... otherwise this could cause unexpected results..

Answer (score 4):

[TextViewCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/TextViewCompat) from AndroidX is the official solution for your problem.

Comment: which works only for 26+ Android, but we can use `AppCompatTextView` and `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
                    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`

Comment: Here's some documentation about the support libraries: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview#using-support-library_1